# Length property not updating on object arrays

Tags: javascript

Two problems consider the following object:

```
//new obj

var obj = {};
obj['cars'] = [];
obj['cars']['toyota'] = 1;
obj['cars']['mazda'] = 0;


console.log(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

1. Why does my cars array have length of 0? Do i have to update the length property manually?
2. Why is my stringified object empty when it has parameters in it i'm assuming it is tied into the length property?

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/wcd7f8Lz/

Comment: Change `cars` to an object. https://jsfiddle.net/u3tsu4gg/. Arrays only have integer-based indexing, not strings like in your example. You can get the length of `cars` with `Object.keys(obj.cars)`.length;

Comment: @andy this works but why does it not work correctly with an array?

Comment: `obj.cars.push('toyota'); obj.cars.push('mazda'); obj.cars.length; // => 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

car is initialized as an array, but used as an Object. and an object does not have length attribute...

To get the length of an object, you can do ̀̀̀̀`Object.keys(obj).length` (get the keys list, and because it is an array, it have a length).

But the problem is also that you initialize cars as an **array**, but use it as **Object**...

see docs here:

> http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

The solution is to initialize it as **Object**:

```
//new obj

var obj = {};
obj['cars'] = {}; //And other object
obj['cars']['toyota'] = 1;
obj['cars']['mazda'] = 0;


console.log(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

But if you want instead a simple array:

```
//new obj
var obj = {};
obj['cars'] = [];
obj['cars'][1] = "toyota";
obj['cars'][0] = "mazda";


console.log(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

The syntax is ̀`array[identifier] = value;`
(and not ̀̀̀̀̀`array[value] = identifier`)

I've updated the fiddle.

Comment: _"car is not an array, it is an Object"_ probably needs rewording because `cars` _is_ an array but can't be assigned string indexes - which is the basis of the question.

Comment: I see in javascript "arrays" must use a numeric index.

Comment: @Andy I edited my post! Thanks for watching after my posts ;)

Answer (score 2):

`obj.cars.length` is 0, because you **don't push** new items in array, but change **it properties**:

```
var obj = {};
obj.cars = [];          // obj.cars is empty array
obj.cars.toyota = 1;    // obj.cars is empty array with a new property toyota
obj.cars.push('mazda'); // obj.cars is array with a new property toyota and one element mazda

console.log(obj.cars instanceof Array,
            obj.cars.length,
            Object.keys(obj.cars)); // output: true 1 ["toyota"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use it in this way?

```
var cars = [];
cars.push({name:'toyota', value:1});
cars.push({name:'mazda', value:0})
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you aren't using an array (despite declaring it with an array literal), you're using it as an object.

Arrays are just a special case of object, meaning they can have individual properties. These properties don't exist "in" the array but instead are properties "of" the array.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.thing = 'a';
console.log(arr.length); // 3
```

To add elements to an array, you should use `push`:

```
var arr = []; // length: 0
arr.push(1);  // length: 1
```

If you want to be able to access an object both by name *and* index then you can combine `push` with custom properties.

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(0);
arr.mazda = 0;
```